# como agrego un Text en flutter

Tags: flutter

como hago para agregar mi Text en el siguiente codigo en flutter:

Text(
'${_productosModel[index].name}',
textAlign: TextAlign.center,
style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
),

/* CODIGO FLUTTER */

```js
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () => Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (BuildContext context) => ImageScreen(
        url: '${_productosModel[index].image}' + '?alt=media',
      ),
    ),
      ),
      child: Expanded(
        child: CachedNetworkImage(
          imageUrl: '${_productosModel[index].image}' + '?alt=media',
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          placeholder: (_, __) {
            return Center(
              child: CupertinoActivityIndicator(
                radius: 15,
              ),
            );
//adicionar Text 
          },
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: Envuelve el `Expanded` en un `Column` y debajo de ese `Expanded` pones el `Text`.

Comment: como quedaria ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   return InkWell(
      onTap: () => Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (BuildContext context) => ImageScreen(
        url: '${_productosModel[index].image}' + '?alt=media',
      ),
    ),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: [
         Expanded(
        child: CachedNetworkImage(
          imageUrl: '${_productosModel[index].image}' + '?alt=media',
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          placeholder: (_, __) {
            return Center(
              child: CupertinoActivityIndicator(
                radius: 15,
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
       // Texto
       Text( '${_productosModel[index].name}', textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),),
      ],
     ),
    ),
```